# How to access element of MainPage.xaml into another page in uwp application?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my uwp application I've added a progress ring and want to use that through out the application.
But when I call that ring from other pages it doesn't work. Here is my code of MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
 <Frame Name="FDMainFrame"></Frame>
 <ProgressRing x:FieldModifier="Public" x:Name="progress1" Height="100" Width="100" Canvas.ZIndex="999"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm calling different pages in FDMainFrame and want to show and hide progress ring based on activity on those page. But I'm not able to access it from other pages. 
Please suggest what should be the best way for achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use the progress ring from other pages , try creating it as UserControl , and you can use it in all the pages as xaml control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the ProgressRing by the current instance of MainPage. This means you can define a static **Current** field on MainPage.cs which can be called from your other paged to get the MainPage instance.

And then use the instance to get the ProgressRing control or you can put the show and hide method in MainPage and directly call the method from other page.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Current = this;
    progress1.IsActive = true;
}

public static MainPage Current;
```

In another page:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage.Current.progress1.IsActive = false;
}
```

or

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage.Current.HideMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what I understand from your question is , you are looking for communicating between multi views.

This [uwp-multi-view-communication](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/uwp-multi-view-communication) will help you understand better.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.